# Using GetLastError when using Dos Commands in C++

Tags: c++, file

So i have a bit of code that uses Dos Commands to try to rename a folder. So

```
system("rename C:\\Users\\me\\SecondDir NewDir);
```

So this tries to rename SecondDir to NewDir. There is already a folder at that location called NewDir so it should fail. And it does. Im then using GetLastError to get the error code returned to ensure the problem is what i expect it to be. But it only ever returns ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES. Which isnt the error i should be getting, which is ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS. Im assuming this is something to do with using the system command?

EDIT: I just checked and i even get ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES returned when a command is successful.

Comment: `GetLastError()` returns the last error that occurred in the calling thread. `system()` spawns another process entirely, so you cannot use `GetLastError()` to get the error that occurred there. Maybe you can use the return value of `system()` instead?

Comment: Or use the win32 `MoveFile` function which will return success and set errors available to `GetLastError`

Comment: Is the return values from system() the same System Error Codes returned by GetLastError do you  know?

Comment: @discodowney, nope, it will be the status code returned by the program itself, which is more limited. Zero usually means success, anything else means something went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetLastError will not return a meaningful value except in the circumstances where it is documented to do so. This is not one of them - the values you are getting are irrelevant and intended for someone else.

To rename a file from C you should  use the C runtime `rename` function not use system to invoke a rename utility.

`GetLastError` is only meaningful immediately after calling a Win32 function which is documented to set the thread Last Error using `SetLastError`. The C equivalent is `errno`, which applies to C functions.

The `rename` function returns -1 on failure and sets `errno`.

E.g.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f(v=VS.80).aspx